# Bounding $\int_0^{\infty} x^p e^{-x} dx$ to find the values of p for integral convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Find all the values of p for which the integral converges
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} x^p e^{-x} dx$$

I am thinking about bounding the integral using
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^p e^{-2x} dx \leq  \int_0^{\infty} x^p e^{-x} dx  \leq  \int_0^{\infty} x^p e^{-0.5x} dx $$

But i do not see those 2 bounds very helpful.

Next option: I was thinking to choose a tangent line as lower bound but can't see one line as upper bound as the original curve runs to infinity.

What could a more adequate approach be here?
Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For $x \in [0,1]$ we have $e^{-1} x^p \leqslant x^p e^{-x} \leqslant x^p$.

This should help you determine convergence and divergence of $\int_0^1 x^p e^{-x} \, dx$ by the comparison test.

For $[1, \infty)$ we have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^p e^{-x}}{x^{-2}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^{p+2}}{ e^{x}} = 0  $$

Since $\int_1^\infty x^{-2} \, dx $ converges, by the limit comparison test $\int_1^\infty x^p e^{-x} \, dx$ converges for all $p$.

Thus, the values of $p$ for which the integral $\int_0^\infty x^p e^{-x} \, dx $ converges/diverges is dictated by the conditions for convergence/divergence of $\int_0^1 x^p e^{-x} \, dx.$ As you will see this is convergence for $p > -1$ and divergence for $p \leqslant -1.$

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more for about the divergence part!

Comment: Since $x^pe^{-x} \geqslant e^{-1} x^p$ on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1 x^p \, dx $ diverges if $p \leqslant -1$.  For example if $p = -1$ we have $\int_c^1 x^{-1} \, dx   = - \log c \to \infty $ as $c \to 0$.

Comment: I found that $$\frac{1}{ep+e} \leq \int_0^1 e^{-x}x^p \leq \frac{1}{p+1}$$ solving $$\frac{1}{ep+e} \leq \frac{1}{p+1}$$ I found $p \leq -1$ Should it mean that the integral converges when $p \leq -1$?

Comment: That is not a correct conclusion. What happens for example if $p = -1$?  We use the inequalities to apply the comparison test which says if $|f(x)| < g(x)$ and $\int_0^1 g $ converges then $\int_0^1 f$ converges. If $f(x) > g(x) >0$ and $\int_0^1 g$ diverges then $\int_0^1 f$ diverges.  As I showed above if $p = -1$ then $\int_0^1 x^p$ diverges like log and using the left inequality $\int_0^1 x^{-1} e^{-x} > e^{-1}\int_0^1 x^{-1} = \infty$.

Comment: Note that for $p \neq -1$, $\int_c^1 x^{p} = (1 - c^{p+1})/(p+1)$.  If $p < -1$ then $c^{p+1} \to \infty$ as $c \to 0$ and $\int_0^1 x^p$ diverges. Since $x^p e^{-x} > e^{-1}x^p$ by the comparison test $\int_0^1 x^p e^{-x}$ diverges for $p \leqslant -1$.

Comment: If $p > -1$ then we see that $c^{p+1} \to 0$ as $c \to 0$ and $\int_0^1 x^p$ converges.  Since $x^p e^{-x} < x^p$, by the comparison test $\int_0^1 x^p e^{-x} $ converges for $p > -1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).   Integrating by parts is one of the main tools...  For $p\in \mathbb{Z_+}$, $\Gamma (p+1)=p!$.  By analytic continuation  $\Gamma$ is defined for all complex numbers except the negative integers. ...